# Add automatic sum labels on top of the Clustered multi-segment stacked column chart with sub-categories using amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to add sum of labels on top of each bar using **amcharts**,but i am unable do it.

When I have only one bar in each category below code works for me

```
"valueAxes": [{      
    "totalText": "[[total]]"
}],
```

but i have sub categories in each category

**See**:https://jsfiddle.net/sumalatha_J/xb89desy/

I need my output to be look like this,can anyone help me with this

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56sFz.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `totalText` doesn't account for stacked bars. Your only option is to create a [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelFunction) on the final column in the stack that sums up the totals, for example:

```
"graphs": [
  // ...
{
      "fillAlphas": 0.9,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2,
      "title": "0100",
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "update01",
      "showAllValueLabels": true,
      "labelText": "[[value]]",
      "labelPosition": "top",
      "labelFunction": function(graphDataItem) {
        return graphDataItem.values.value + graphDataItem.dataContext.support01 + graphDataItem.dataContext.feature01 + graphDataItem.dataContext.priority01
      }
    },
     // repeat for each update* graph in each stack
```

Note that you have to set a [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelText) for the `labelFunction` to trigger and set [`labelPosition`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelPosition) to `"top"`. [`showAllValueLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showAllValueLabels) is also recommended if you need to force the labels to appear when the area is too small.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xb89desy/1/)